# Serious Problem with special characters and multi-languages

Tags: php, javascript

I created a simple comment wall that submits using ajax.

Using javascript i collect user input:

```
var sharetxt =  encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("cw_share_txt").value);
```

then pass it to a php page, on the php page, i collect the passed data:

```
$text=nl2br(htmlentities(trim(utf8_decode($_POST["txt"]))));
```

Encoding of the php page above:

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

My problem is that

1. the wall doesnt still support multi languages (displays as ???? and causes my xml not to work)
2. i still problems with some special characters (displays as Ã¢Â�Â� or ?)

**What am i not doing right? please assist**

Comment: try changing the charset to `utf-16`

Answer (score 0):

The magic left when you called `utf8_decode`.  Did you have a good reason for doing that?  Also, shouldn't your page be XHTML instead of true XML?

Comment: i used the utf8_decode when i was having issues with passing the xml back to javascript (xml was complaining of some unknown xters). the xml im talkin bout here is in my php process page.

Comment: @Ogugua Belonwu: If you call `utf8_decode`, you strip all the characters that don't fit in ISO-8859-1 from the document.  That's no good.  I don't know the correct function for putting arbitrary UTF-8 into XML, but that's not it.

Comment: i have removed the utf_decode and it doesnt still display right eg. '(Hydrog�ologie, 1802).[4][5] It was inspired by the Greek word ????, bios, "life" and the suffix -?????, -logia, "study of' instead of ' (Hydrogéologie, 1802).[4][5] It was inspired by the Greek word βίος, bios, "life" and the suffix -λογία, -logia, "study of'

Answer (score 0):

instead of utf8_decode have you tried:

```
mb_convert_encoding($str, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
```

That should solve the beef XML has with your text I think.